# How to reduce the APK file size in Unity3d 5.6

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to reduce the app size in Unity 5.6, I have a problem with this because its default build size shows 19 Mb. How can in reduce the file sizes

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) about this topic